# Align gridlines with ticks in base R plot

Tags: r, plot

[image: the pic]

I saw this picture on the Internet, and just wondered how to plot it in R. This is my code:

```
article <- data.frame(x = as.Date(round(runif(1000), 2) * 100, origin = '2017-01-01'), y = sample(letters[1:10], 1000, T))
plot(article$x, article$y, pch = 19, col = article$y, xlab = 'date', ylab = 'account', yaxt = 'n') + grid(nx = 10, ny = 10, lty = 1, col = 'grey')
axis(2, at = 1:10, label = levels(article$y))
```

[image: my pic]

And I got a picture like this. There is still a problem: the gridline on the y axis does not correspond to the axis label. So how to solve this problem, or is there a more direct method for rendering the plot?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix the arguments of `grid()` so that it gives what you want but you could use `plot()` to draw a blank plot, use `abline()` to draw the grid, then plot the data on it using `points()`.

So using your data

```
plot(article$x, article$y, type="n", xlab = 'date', ylab = 'account', yaxt = 'n', xaxt = 'n') 
abline(h=1:10, v=pretty(article$x), col="grey")
points(article$x, article$y, pch = 19, col = article$y) 
axis(2, at = 1:10, label = levels(article$y))
axis(1, at = pretty(article$x), label = format(pretty(article$x), "%b"))
```

Or just plot the data as you're doing and draw the grid afterwards using `abline()`, but in doing so the grid will be drawn on top of your data points.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` produces a graph very similar to the first picture you included in your post:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

article %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour=y)) + geom_point() + theme_light() + labs(x='date', y='account')
```

[image]